# cv2.findContours() can't find the contours perfectly

Tags: python, opencv

so I am trying to refill black holes in the image using contours, here is the original image:

[image]

I then tried to use this code to fill this only small black hole in the upper half of the image, my intentions is to remove all these unwanted noise in the lower half of the image by bitwise anding it with an image that only contains the contour with the largest area, anyways, here is the code that I tried:

```
blankImage = maskImage # cv2.bitwise_not(maskImage)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blankImage, cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
maxAreaContour = max(contours, key = cv2.contourArea)
blankImage = np.zeros(maskImage.shape, dtype='uint8')
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(blankImage,[cnt],0,125,-1)
```

where blank image is the above image (original image), and then I tried to show what is the drawn contours and here is the result:

[image]

so why is that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the upper black part of the image contains pixels that are non-zeros (values are close to zero but not zero).
When applying `cv2.findContours`, the non-zero pixels are considered part of a contour (all pixels in range [1, 255] are considered "white pixels").

---

Example for non-zero black pixels:

[image]

---

We may apply thresholding using `cv2.threshold` before `cv2.drawContours`:

```
blankImage = cv2.threshold(maskImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Apply binary thresholding with automatic threshold
```

The values that are close to zero are going to be thresholded to zero, and the white pixels are going to be 255.

---

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

maskImage = cv2.imread('original_image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # Read image as grayscale.

#blankImage = maskImage # cv2.bitwise_not(maskImage)
blankImage = cv2.threshold(maskImage, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]  # Apply binary thresholding with automatic threshold
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(blankImage, cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
maxAreaContour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)
blankImage = np.zeros(maskImage.shape, dtype='uint8')
for cnt in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(blankImage, [cnt], 0, 125, -1)

# Show result for testing
cv2.imshow('blankImage', blankImage)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`blankImage`:
[image]

Comment: I really appreciate it, you made my day as I have been hazing around for quite some time , but can you tell me how did you get that value of each individual pixel, is it a type of program or what?

Comment: For the above example I used MATLAB and imtool, but at first I just examined the image using paint.net. I assumed it is the problem, because it's the only possible explanation.